# jQuery Background-size Width AND Height values

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set the width AND height for the background-size, however jQuery will only let me use one value no matter what I try, it gets rid of the height.

I am currently setting the width dynamically with a variable, but now need to add a static height. Any ideas on a solution for this problem?

I have tried the following code:

```
var itemResize = $(".slider-container ul li, .slider-container .blurlayer");

$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    itemResize.css({ backgroundSize : windowWidth });
}).resize();
```

Comment: Note: Even this will not work

.css({ backgroundSize : "570px 570px" });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide only one value, the browser will apply it to both width & height attributes.

Here is a link for you to experiment with the different values possible for this parameter:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size

Note : It looks like the css property is `background-size` (even though `backgroundSize` seems to work too)

Comment: Well, the problem is even is I use two static values in jQuery (background-size OR backgroundSize), it will only spit out the first value, always.

Comment: Providing two parameters works for me on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2QetT/

Comment: Nice! Writing it that way works, I was just writing it out wrong. How would I use the variable I have for the width, with a static height?

Comment: I think you have to build a string to provide values and the corresponding units. For ex: `windowWidth + 'px ' + windowHeight + 'px' `

Comment: Changing css property from backgroundSize to background-size worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the background width and height at the same time, even if the height does not change.

`itemResize.css({ backgroundSize : windowWidth+' '+staticHeight });`

Comment: Trying this, and it's not adding background-size at all on the div's. This issue is a huge pain, it's making no sense on why nothing is working.

Comment: My answer was derived from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp.  Also be sure you are adding the correct units of measure.

Answer (score 0):

Both the width and height have to be set together, but as strings:

```
var itemResize = $(".slider-container ul li, .slider-container .blurlayer");

$(window).resize(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width() + 'px';
  var windowHeight = '100px';
  itemResize.css({ backgroundSize : windowWidth + ' ' + windowHeight });
}).resize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however now it is not even adding the background-size to the div's with that code.

Comment: I've updated the code above to reflect that it needs the 'px' in it as strings.

Comment: Did you actually try this? It seems to me that you cannot set background-size with jquery. background-image, background-position, can be set, but jquery ignores background-size for some reason.