# JQuery CSS two values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to give my bg pic, both a height and a weight with! But it will only let me set one value! Does anybody know what to do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('body').css('background-size', windowHeight, '100%');
  };
  setHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

Comment: Do it with clean js: `document.body.style.cssText = 'width:100%; height:100%';`

Comment: i not intended it to be in the body there shot be styled, but a full screen div.

Comment: create a function setWidth that does the same thing but with width, and call it in the resize function?

Comment: Well it's the same thing. Select the element somehow (`document.querySelector(...)` maybe?) and then `elem.style.cssText = 'styles here...';`

Comment: What is the desired CSS result? I find the question a bit unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Background-size Width AND Height values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112829/jquery-background-size-width-and-height-values)

Comment: You might also want to look into `background-size: cover|contain`.

Answer (score 4):

Put the width and height together in a string. The first value sets the width and the second value sets the height. And `.innerHeight()` returns just a value so you need to add `px`.

```
 $('body').css('background-size', '100% ' + windowHeight + 'px');
```

Comment: No, he is missing a space between the values.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you want to get your background-image to fill the whole body. 
You can easily achieve this via css properties.

```
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
background-size: contain;
```

Here's one of many tutorials: 
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[DEMO](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php)

Comment: it is for get set same a resualte like background-size: cover; but it have to work on iphone

Comment: shouldn't be a problem http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts just be sure to add it to the html and not to the body - appending it to the body is known to create strange behaviors